# Builder beta custom slot types. insert a lot of data at once

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a little question about the Builder beta for ASK. i made my own custom slot type and wanted to copy paste my data into it as i normally do without the beta BUT it does not auto enters it into it because it is not made like a list like it was before the beta.

Now my question to you, how can i paste in 3500 Names into this custom slot without ctrl+c ctrl+v and enter one by one? I can write a quick script to generate the code and paste the code but should there not be a fast way for not programmers?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The schema for the interaction model has been updated but the new format is simple. Here is an example... just follow this format and you'll be able to copy and paste with all of your names.

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
      "invocationName": "example model",
      "intents": [
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
          "samples": []
        },
        {
          "name": "CurrencyStatusIntent",
          "slots": [
            {
              "name": "currencyName",
              "type": "CRYPTOCURRENCIES"
            }
          ],
          "samples": [
            "{currencyName}",
            "get an update on {currencyName}",
            "get the status of {currencyName}",
            "tell me about {currencyName}"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "types": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "id":null,
              "name": {
                "value": "bitcoin",
                "synonyms": []
              }
            },
            {
              "id":null,
              "name": {
                "value": "ethereum",
                "synonyms": []
              }
            },
            {
              "id":null,
              "name": {
                "value": "litecoin",
                "synonyms": [
                  "light coin"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "CRYPTOCURRENCIES"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you might want to take a look at using the [ASK-CLI](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-intro.html) to publish your model. Makes it way simpler than using the Builder beta and copy / paste. If you have not used it, here is a video I did that provides a quick intro. https://youtu.be/p-zlSdixCZ4

Comment: hi there, thx for your answer but this is actually not at all what i am looking for. this is my model right now http://pasted.co/760faa6d and here i need to enter my names. i need to use the beta because i want to use the dialog part of Alexa and in their documentation they are saying you have to use the beta for it to work so that is what i am doing. i already solved my problem by running a small script that puts it in but i just hoped there would be a faster way ;).

Comment: hi @Liam, sorry that isn't what you are looking for. For clarity, the example I provided is based on the new schema so it can also support dialogs and the dialog interface - I'm just not using it in that example. I did the same thing for one of my skills that has about 20K values for one custom slot type - also used a script to generate the schema. Anyhow, glad to know it's all working.

Comment: no problem at all. it is just wierd that there is not like an insert csv or some kind of input for non programers. for me and you it easy to write this script in 5 sec but i can imagine for a on programer it can be a lot harder or a turn down if they cannot get it fixed. i was thinking about using ASK_CLI and got it installed and everything but just did not get really to it but might look it up for my second skill ;) thanks for the info though.

Comment: I agree 100% - it should be way simpler. In fact, they reason I really like the ASK-CLI is because the Skill Builder Beta still pretty limited in my opinion. It's great for simple skills but as soon as you start doing something like what you're trying to do it's not a great option. I'd take a second look at the ASK-CLI - I think you'll really like it.